# RegEx for matching any char except numbers and defined words

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I'm trying to batch rename my files using Advanced Renamer, that support `regex`.

I want to match all characters to exclude those and create a new filename, but maintain numbers of episodes and specifics words to differentiate regular episodes that OVAs, for example.

I tried `\D[^OVA]` and others similar but nothing works:

> Hunter x Hunter 02 = 02
>
> Hunter x Hunter OVA 08 = OVA 08
>
> Hunter x Hunter OVA Greed Island Final 01 = OVA Island 01

Comment: You need to use a negative lookahead to not match a word.

Comment: It's not quite clear as to what's your input filename and what you want to change it into. Can you specify the current filenames and what you want them to become after renaming? Also, how are you doing the regex operation. I guess you must be replacing and not matching.

Comment: Actual name: Hunter x Hunter OVA Greed Island Final 01
Expected name: OVA Island 01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you wish to exclude OVA and all your numbers. Then, [this expression](https://regex101.com/r/9LdFpm/1) may help you to do so or design one:

```
([^OVA0-9]+)*
```

[image]

#### Graph

This graph shows how the expression would work and you can visualize other expressions in this [link](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

---

If you wish to add a list of word to exclude, [this expression](https://regex101.com/r/1t3SVZ/1) may do so:

```
([\S\s]*?)([0-9]+|OVA|Any|Thing|Else|That|You|Like)
```

You can add any other word that you might want using an <kbd>|</kbd> to exclude.

[image]

#### RegEx Descriptive Graph

[image]

#### JavaScript Test

```js
const regex = /([\S\s]*?)([0-9]+|OVA|Any|Thing|Else|That|Like)/gm;
const str = `Hunter x Hunter VOA Greed Island Final 01 = OVA Island 01`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: Exact Emma, but in your code Regex consider O V A like single characters, I want that consider as a word because if in the expression has a single character O, for example, I want this O is not excluded.
Sorry for my English.

Comment: This code - ([\S\s]*?)([0-9]+|OVA|Any|Thing|Else|That|You|Like) - select all characters, but instead of deleting everything except the words that I choose I changed in app to delete everything and replace with group 2 and it worked perfectly! Thanks a lot for help.